# How to prevent the user to create more than one ticket in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

To do this I had to check first if the ticket already existed or not but I have problems:

- if I specify a channel to None each time it will tell me that the channel exists and therefore create several tickets channels.
- And if I don't set channel before, it won't be defined

Here is the part of the code about the creation of the ticket when the user chooses his option:

```
async def mycallback(interaction): 
 if select.values[0] == "01": 
  await interaction.response.defer(ephemeral=True)
  category = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, name="Ticket")
  username = interaction.user.name
  channel = None
  for chan in category.channels: 
     if username in chan.name: 
      channel = chan
      break
  if channel == None: 
      channel = await guild.create_text_channel(f"{interaction.user.name}-ticket", category=category,overwrites=overwrite)
      await interaction.followup.send(f"Created ticket - <#{channel.id}>", ephemeral=True)
      view2 = View(timeout=None)
      view2.add_item(select2)
      view2.add_item(button)
      await channel.send('Hello, how can I help ?', view=view2)
  else: 
      await interaction.followup.send("You already have a ticket open, please close it to open a new ticket")
```

How to solve this ? If the user already has a ticket he should not be able to open a second one

**EDITED**

Answer (score 3):

Your code will *always* create a new channel as you're setting channel to None and then immediately creating a channel.

You either need to be storing some data outside this block of code (either some kind of data structure somewhere, a file locally, or in a database) that tells you if a user has an open ticket and which channel ID it is. Or, you need to search the channels in the 'Tickets' category for an existing channel with that user's name.

For the latter, something like this:

```py
async def mycallback(interaction):
    if select.values[0] == "01":
        # i always like to defer early
        await interaction.response.defer(ephemeral=True)
        category = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, name="Ticket")
        user_name = interaction.user.name
        channel = None
        for chan in category.channels:
            if user_name in chan.name:
                channel = chan
                break
        if not channel:   
            # create the channel
        else:
            # tell the user they have one already
```

Comment: It still create multiple channels with the name

Comment: Can you add something to the original question with the new function/code?

Comment: It's edited like that it doesn't work

Comment: anything new ???